# Automatic Weights in Armature only linking joints

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

I rigged my armature fairly normally. I'm using Rigify with the human armature. Everything is going smoothly but once I enter pose mode it shows that the armature is incorrectly rigged. This is where things go a little too smoothly. Rather than have joints at the corners it's almost as though it were a smooth curve trying to hit all the corners in a line. I imagine this is just a setting that I have incorrectly set or something because I have done this exact process before and have had no problems.

Here is a picture of an upper arm being lifted up:

[image: As you can see the mesh is clearly outside of where the armature is]

Comment: hello, the vertices must be part of other vertex groups, please share your file so that we can check: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/7a85829428494adbaa1e712ddce9f175

Here is the file. If you go into pose mode you should be able to see the curvature if you bend the limbs. I didn't set the vertex groups manually. Am I incorrect in assuming that "with Automatic Weights" automatically sets them? If it doesn't do that then what does it do?